# Remove Item in a Listbox by selecting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list box which is based on the worksheet range. I put a button included in my Userform that deletes the selected item inside my listbox whenever it is clicked. And everytime there is a deleted item there, **the deleted item should also be removed** in my Worksheet range. ***Here's my code in removing the item in the listbox:***

```
Private Sub btnRemove_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

How to remove the deleted item in the worksheet range? Thank you! :)

Comment: it will be easier to assist you if you provide more info about your range, like the worksheet where your range is located, and how the data is located there

Comment: How you have assigned the range to the ListBox1 ? Did you assign it in Listbox1 property ListFillRange ?

Comment: Hi Shai Rado - The range is only from C32 to C41. No more than that. Values from that range are the values included in my listbox.

Answer (score 3):

since you're using `.RemoveItem()` method you must have set your listbox range via its `List` property and not with `RowSource` one

then you could use this code in your userform code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim listRng As Range '<-- declare a Userform scoped variable of 'Range' type to track the range whose content you fill your ListBox1 with (for instance, in Userform_Initialize())

Private Sub btnRemove_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowsList As String

    For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            ListBox1.RemoveItem i
        Else
            rowsList = rowsList & i + 1 & " " '<-- update the rows to be confirmed
        End If
    Next i
    If rowsList <> "" Then UpdateListRange Left(rowsList, Len(rowsList) - 1)
End Sub

Sub UpdateListRange (rowsList As String)
    Dim addr As String
    Dim iRow As Variant
    Dim rowsListArr As Variant

    rowsListArr = Split(rowsList)
    For iRow = UBound(rowsListArr) To LBound(rowsListArr) Step -1
        addr = addr & listRng(rowsListArr(iRow)).address(False, False) & ","
    Next iRow

    If addr <> "" Then addr = Left(addr, Len(addr) - 1)
    Set listRng = listRng.Parent.Range(addr)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Worksheets("List").Range("C32:C41") '<-- change "List" to your actual worksheet name with the range whose content you fill ListBox1 list with
        Me.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.Cells) '<-- fill ListBox1 list
        Set listRng = .Cells '<-- set the userform scoped range variable to track the "listbox filling" range
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @kruk22, did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine without the "-1" for whatever reason.

```
Private Sub btnRemove_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount 
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```